# adding image with paperclip failed NoHandlerError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paperclip

Using Paperclip 6.1.0 in rails 6 I got this error:

**Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError**
(No handler found for "logo.jpg"):

In my model I have:

```
 class Movie < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :screens
  has_many :tickets


  has_attached_file :blob, styles: {
      thumb: '100x100>',
      square: '200x200#',
      medium: '300x300>'
  }

  # Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
  validates_attachment_content_type :blob, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

The exception is raised at:

```
  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
    if @movie.save
      redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.'
    else
```

with params:

```
    Parameters:

{"authenticity_token"=>"fzm4JrC/eGQsDUS04w52lfI7B5hC6agpSRtyn+4BSayWxRt1RG/lZDNypxxWVmcSZfaW6+HQ+auNJm7p43p/LQ==",
 "movie"=>{"title"=>"test", "description"=>"345", "movie_length"=>"4r", "age_limit"=>"345", "price"=>"345", "category"=>"345", "blob"=>"Screen Shot 2020-12-30 at 10.24.49.png"},
 "commit"=>"Create Movie"}
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @movie do |f|%>
  <%= form_for @movie, html: { multipart: true } do |f|%>
    <div class="form-group">
      <% if @movie.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@movie.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this movie from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
            <% @movie.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
<%# <div class="field"> %>
      <%= f.label :title %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Title" %>
    </div>
   
      <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :blob %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :blob, class: "form-control", placeholder: "blob" %>
</div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
<%# f.submit will automatically give it a create or update button %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Is `blob` supposed to be the preview image for a movie? Thats a pretty stange choice for a name.

Comment: Yea, well I can change it. but I guess this is not the problem?

Comment: No the problem is most likely that you are sending regular formdata instead of multipart. The parameters should contain an instance of  `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`  and not just a string. I'm guessing this was sent through a form submission (and not a test)? Can you add the form?

Comment: @max  i have add the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two calls to `form_for` nested inside of each other. That will create `<form ...><form...>` which is not valid HTML. [Form elements may not be nested inside of each other](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#elementdef-form) and the behavior is hightly unpredicable. Usually the submit button will submit the outer form element but since this is non-standard anything could happen.

Remove the outer call to `<%= form_for(@movie) do |f| %>` and use a file field input and not a text input:

```
<%= form_for @movie, html: { multipart: true } do |f|%>
  <div class="form-group">
    <% if @movie.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@movie.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this movie from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
            <% @movie.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :title %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Title" %>
    </div>
   
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :blob %><br>
      <%= f.file_field :blob, class: "form-control", placeholder: "blob" %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```